# How do I update a field of a record using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to do 2 things. The first is to get the id of a record of the Client table and convert it to integer. My query is okay for that but how do I accomplish the second task - that is to update the record in the Investments table (field: Client_ID) to the first mentioned id. Thanks for your help. Maybe there's a better way to do this.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,LastName,Fund,PurchaseDate,Shares,PurchasePrice,PurchaseAmount")] Investments investments)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Ports.Add(investments);
        db.SaveChanges();
        //db.SaveChanges();

        // write the Client_ID to the saved record

        // first get the ID of the client
        var q = (from c in context.Clients
                 where c.LastName == investments.LastName
                 select new
                 {
                     c.ID
                 }).ToList();

        // next update the Client_ID of the Investment record
        var result = (from p in context.Investments
                         where (p.LastName == investments.LastName)
                         && (p.Client_ID == null)
                         select p);

       //I'm not sure what to do next 

        //Context.SaveChanges();


        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(investments);
}



 ++++++++++++++ new code 12/22/2016 - controller +++++++++++++++++

        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,LastName,Fund,PurchaseDate,Shares,PurchasePrice,PurchaseAmount")] Investments investments)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var clientId = (from c in context.Clients
                                where c.LastName == investments.LastName
                                select new
                                {
                                    c.ID
                                }).ToList().First();

                var productList = System.Collections.Generic.IList < Investments >{ investments };

                foreach (var investment in investments)
                {
                    investment.Client_ID = clientId;
                }
                db.Ports.Add(investments);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }

            return View(investments);
        }
     +++++++++++++++++++++ model Investments +++++++++++++++++++++

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace StockHoldings.Models
{
    public class Investments
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Fund { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1, 1000)]
        public int Shares { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(0.01, 200.00)]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public double PurchasePrice { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public double PurchaseAmount { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: Unclear what your wanting to do here. Why in the world does you `Investment` model contain a property `LastName` which seems to relate to a `Client`, when it should contain a FK property for the Client

Comment: @StephenMuecke is right, if the LastName of Investement is related to the client that means your data model is not normalized. In relational DB you MUST NOT duplicate data or you will end up with data inconsistency (I.E if your client updates his last name then you will have to update all his investments or your data are will be inconsistent, this should not work this way in a relational DB)

Comment: Added C# tag as your post is using C# language. This will help you reach more audiences.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the entities as Modified:

```
foreach(var toUpdate in result){
    toUpdate.Client_ID = q.First(); // or int.Parse(q.First());
    Context.Entry(toUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

Context.SaveChanges();
```

But why don't you actually update the investements before inserting them:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,LastName,Fund,PurchaseDate,Shares,PurchasePrice,PurchaseAmount")] Investments investments)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var clientId = (from c in context.Clients
             where c.LastName == investments.LastName
             select new
             {
                 c.ID
             }).ToList().First();

        foreach(var investment in investements){
             investment.Client_ID = clientId;
        }
        db.Ports.Add(investments);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(investments);
}
```

The true questions here are:

1. why retrieving the clientid with it's last name? Is it a good idea ? Maybe your endpoint should also receive the clientId ?
2. can't you already pass the clientId to the initial view bad or data and build your investments objects already with this property set at front end ?

Comment: foreach(var investment in investements){
             investment.Client_ID = clientId;

Comment: foreach(var investment in investements){
             investment.Client_ID = clientId;           @Piou - The StockHoldings.Models.Investments does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator.

Comment: foreach(var investment in investements){
             investment.Client_ID = clientId;           @Piou - Error on this line. The StockHoldings.Models.Investments does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator.

Comment: foreach(var investment in investements){
             investment.Client_ID = clientId;           @Piou - Error on this line. "The StockHoldings.Models.Investments does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator.".

Comment: No need to post it 3 times :)
There is something I have trouble to understand in your code and in your data model. What is your `Models`.investments` class and how is that so different from `context.Investments` ?
From what I see in your original code, you add investments to your `db.Ports` and then you retrieve them in the `context` to update their client id?

Comment: Piou - the code as it stands now is in the first textbox above, marked

Comment: the code as it stands now is in the first textbox above, marked      ++++++++++++++ new code 12/22/2016 - controller +++++++++++++++++
I've included the Investments model for you to look at. Any further help would be appreciated. <From what I see in your original code, you add investments to your db.Ports and then you retrieve them in the context to update their client id?> Yes, I saw that Client_ID was not being updated at all.